# JavaScript popup result from a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the first time I am trying to make a popup working.
I have done research over the internet but I could not see what I do wrong 
Perhaps you guys can see something wrong here. 
I will just link the form en the javascript for avoiding long script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.popup').popupWindow({ 
height:500, 
width:800, 
top:50, 
left:50 
}); 
</script>
```

And the form:

```
echo "<form action='getlist.php' method='post'> 
                    <input type='text' name='exte' class='exte' value=".$value['ext'].">  
                    <input type='submit' name='aanvragen' class='popup' id='aanvragen' value='aanvragen'></form>";
                    echo "</td>";
```

I want it to open getlist.php in a popup screen ;) 
*Thanks*

Edit: When I click on the button it just go to getlist.php in a full screen
I want this to be in a popup

Comment: `I want it to open getlist.php in a popup screen` And I want to know what really happens. Or I should imagine?

Comment: Thanks for the -1;) 
What happens.. Okay, in getlist.php there is a javascript datepicker, wich turns the value of the picked date into a  php variable. to get to the datepicker user have to click on a button, he will have a popup and can choose his date by using javascript datepicker

Comment: We are facing an XY problem here. Your datepicker can easily be placed in the form itself, without using a popup. If you need server side validation, use `AJAX` to send your date values. In fact, it's better you don't use any popups at all. Popup blockers will break the functionality of your page.

Comment: but I want it to be placed in a popup.

Comment: Use your popup to display information, not save information.

Comment: but it has to pickup the date once there is a popin, not on the page itself, I will make a screenshot of getlist.php, just a second

Comment: Alright, maybe we can figure something out together.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Yq0ZECu.png 
this is exactly what I want to be placed in a popup

Edit: when clicked on "kies een datum"
http://i.imgur.com/VIuGxt8.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68712/discussion-between-haltlolxd-and-mysteryos).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, your jQuery `popupWindow` is probably being called before the echo ever puts anything on the page so the listener never registers its self.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a link like this :

```
<a href="#" id="openPopup">Open form</a>
```

Then open in javascript something like this :

```
window.open ('popup.php', 'windowName', config='height=100, width=400, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
```

And you have your form in `popup.php`.

Comment: I believe he is trying to post data to a popup window. In which case, your above answer would not be applicable.

Comment: Exactly, it actually have to show result, well it have simply to load getlist.php in a popup

Comment: As anyway if you want to display in a popup you have to open it and inject data inside with a php page so my solution is one of the only way to do it. You can't directly post to a popup, you have two options : 1) post to a page that open a popup and display result inside 2) my solution, open the form in the popup.

Comment: I dont really get it,
echo "<form action='#'  method='post'> 
<input type='text' name='exte' class='exte' value=".$value['ext']."> 
<input type='submit' name='aanvragen' id='openPopup' value='aanvragen'></form>";

Does not work like this

Comment: Non it won't submit your form to the popup because your form action is # and you don't use any ajax to post values. Come back again to my last comment ;)