# Can I set the response of a form submission to the content of a dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I had a question about JavaScript Popup here  [JavaScript popup result from a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916977/javascript-popup-result-from-a-form/27919247#27919247)

Now I was wondering, since no one could really help me out here, not even the internet!

is it possible to use JavaScript Dialog to show the result of a form with action "..php"
I could not find it.

situation:

imagine, we got 2 php files, index.php and test.php 
is it possible to make a form with a submit button on index.php, with action="test.php"
but that the file test.php will get loaded in a JavaScript Dialog.

something like this: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

```
echo "<form action='getlist.php' method='post'> 
            <input type='text' name='exte' class='exte' value=".$value['ext'].">  
            <input type='submit' name='aanvragen' id='aanvragen' value='aanvragen'></form>";
            echo "</td>";
```

This is what I have, now I want the getlist.php get loaded in a popup or Dialog.

I hope that I've been clear about my question, I am trying to get this working for hours now and quite lost my mind.

Comment: It is possible. You would need to submit the form via AJAX and then instantiate the dialog manually using the responsetext as the content.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. One way is to use Ajax to post the form and place the returned page in the popup.

Comment: Possible dupe of OP's own Q here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916977/javascript-popup-result-from-a-form/27919247#27919247 To be fair to Haltlol, s/he's linked quite openly to this so I just wonder if a mod should close one or the other for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is, shouldn't even be very hard, just submit the form with ajax and show the result in a dialog

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
         url  : $(this).attr('action'),
         type : $(this).attr('method'),
         data : $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {
         $('#dialog').html(data).dialog(settings);
    });
});
```

Comment: wow fast answer. Looks good, I like that it uses the forms set action and method. Will have to store this on my snippets for future use. Upvote for you.

Comment: Fast answer! Do I need to change my html form for using this?

Comment: @HaltlolXD - generally you shouldn't have to change anything, but it all depends on markup and what the form returns etc.

Comment: I have copied the JavaScript in my code, still not working. trying to figure out why because the code seems good to me! I will provide screenshots so you can see what I want to do with getlist.php
http://i.imgur.com/VIuGxt8.png
This is what I want to see in the Dialog:)

Comment: Then you need to debug, try it like this, and see what you get in the console -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2e8ueqq6/**

Comment: when I click on submit, it still send me to getlist.php, seems like it does not have the time to even open a dialog

Comment: Then the code isn't running at all, and you have to check  your console for errors.